Installing door seal with MVHR system to prevent noise?
UK based, small apartment. I have a windowless bathroom with shower, and one mechanical ventilation heat recovery system (MVHR) linked exhaust. As such, installing a fan would involve some serious work. The issue is that bathroom noises are quite loud. I am wondering if I can install a door seal or automatic door bottom. I understand the issue with air circulation, but I am wondering if this would be such a problem if we just left the bathroom door open when not in use. My understanding is that the MVHR moves air quite slowly, so having the door sealed for a few minutes at a time may not be an issue.
My question is similar to this one but I am specifically looking for advice with the MVHR exhaust.

It's probably not a problem. As you said, the door isn't closed but for a short amount of time out of a day. Also, no bathroom door is submarine grade. There's still lots of air slipping through the jamb gaps.
I'd say it's worth a try. I'd probably use the type that automatically lowers upon closure. Having a sweep drag across the floor is annoying and could wear on the flooring.
